# How to fix Flutter app occasionally showing white screen on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Flutter App Sometimes Stays on White Screen on IOS

The situation facing after send build to App Store Connect. I can't facing and detect on debug and Android.

I tried:
Flutter clean,
IOS Build Folder Clean,

```
flutter build ios --release
```

EDIT:
I detected Firebase error. I didn't see white screen after Firebase's initialize command I add to commentLine.

Comment: Try to see  if you have any UI warnings in your console . As it will work in your debug build but it wont work in release builds.

Comment: @Swayangjit i detected the error, look my Edit please

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. The app functioned seamlessly in the emulator, but when I attempted to test it on a real device, it became stuck on the initial white page. The solution turned out to be straightforward. Because it ran smoothly on the emulator, I overlooked checking the app log in Android Studio, assuming it wouldn't display any errors. However, upon running the app, I noticed an error in the log. This error led to a crash on the real device. It's crucial to always pay attention to the log, even when the app appears to be working fine in the emulator.